# simple filter I can add to my controller actions that check authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc

some actions shouldn't be run unless the user is logged in.

I just want to do something like:

[MustBeLoggedIn]
public ActionResult Blah()
{
}

is that hard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about [Authorize] attribute and probably FormsAuthentication.

This blog entry shows overview:

[ASP.NET 2.0 Forms authentication - Keeping it customized yet simple](http://blog.codevelop.dk/post/2007/11/24/ASPNET-20-Forms-authentication-Keeping-it-customized-yet-simple.aspx)

This is another page about forms authentication:

[Explained: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx)

When you use forms authentication, set IPrincipal in proper place [Authorize] attribute will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This and other q's answered in [the nerd dinner tutorial](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html).  It's worth an afternoon going through.  (It's free)